# Use 'Face' filter for Image type when using Google Image Search API in Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use the following Python code to grab images from Google:

```
BASE_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&rsz=large&q=%s&start=%d'

BASE_URL = BASE_URL %(name, count)
request = urllib2.Request(BASE_URL)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Then I load the response in a JSON format using simplejson.
Is there any way I could use the Search by Image type as 'Face' so that I could retrieve only the faces using Python?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your answer is in the argument list here:

https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide#json_args

Comment: hello, that link not works. Maybe https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes   works better.  Walk trhough Supported attributes  and look at Refinement elements   > image_type